# PHP GET Form Based on Leading Characters of User Input

Tags: php, forms

I am looking for a way to direct a PHP form to a specific URL based on the user input.  For example:

If user enters AA123 the URL would be http://sample.com/cgi-bin/lookup.cgi?OPT_M=**AA**_DETAIL&TICKET=**AA123**

If user enters BB123 the URL would be http://sample.com/cgi-bin/lookup.cgi?OPT_M=**BB**_DETAIL&TICKET=**BB123**

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Added:

I am able to create 2 separate radio buttons to accomplish this but would really like to do it without selecting the type.  I am not sure where to go next.  Below is what I have so far:

`<form action="http://sample.com/cgi-bin/ticket.cgi" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="OPT_M" value="AA_DETAIL" />AA
    <input type="radio" name="OPT_M" value="BB_DETAIL" />BB
    Ticket: <input type="text" name="Ticket" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Where the user enter those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.. if you are using PHP

On top of the page:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $TICKET = $_GET['Ticket'];
    $OPT_M = substr($TICKET, 0, 2) . '_DETAIL';
    header('Location: http://sample.com/cgi-bin/lookup.cgi?OPT_M=' . $OPT_M . '&TICKET=' . $TICKET);
}
```

On your form:

```
    <form action="#" method="get">
    Ticket: <input type="text" name="Ticket" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Location: mapage.php'); ?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php

Try something than return to the website if you found any problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment instead of an answer but I'm newbie in SO and I need 50 reputation to be able to writte a comment.

I'm not sure if this can help you...

Are you writting your code based on a MVC pattern? If not, this would help you, I think.

I mean, maybe if you send the information to a generic page (controller), you split the variables in a way you know if AA or BB was written, and then you send it to the appropiate page, you could solve your problem.

Something like:

```
$var1 = $_REQUEST['var1'];
$v1 = substr($var1,0,2);
$v2 = substr($var1,2);
```

And after you go to the page with header('location') in which you lead the specific page when you already know the values of your variables.

Sorry for the english level. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple if/else condition:

```
<?php
$user = "";
if($user == "AA123"){
    header('Location: http://example.com/cgi-bin/lookup.cgi?OPT_M=AA_DETAIL&TICKET=AA123');
}
if($user == "AA123"){
    header('Location: http://example.com/cgi-bin/lookup.cgi?OPT_M=AA_DETAIL&TICKET=BB123');
}
?>
```